# How to change colour for each sorting algorithms step in tkinter

Tags: python, sorting, user-interface, tkinter

This is my main code that creates a GUI. The user can enter the numbers or generate random numbers and it will sort it. However, i want it to change colour with each step taken in the sorting algorithm, and then change to a green colour once the array has been sorted.

```
import random

from tkinter import *

import Swap

numberArray = list()

def arrayList(number):
    arrayListEntry.delete(0, END)
    numberArray.append(number)
    e.config(text=str(numberArray))
    print numberArray

def randomiser():
    for i in range(10):
        numberArray.append(random.randint(1,100))
        e.config(text=str(numberArray))
        print numberArray


# Main selection sort function
def selectionSort(numberList):
    for i in range(len(numberList)):

        minimumIndex = i
        print("\nMinimum index: " + str(minimumIndex))

        for l in range(i + 1, len(numberList)):
            if numberList[minimumIndex] > numberList[l]:
                minimumIndex = l
        print(numberArray)
        Swap.startSwap(numberList, i, minimumIndex)
        e.config(text=str(numberArray))
        root.update()
        root.after(1000)
        e.config(text=str(numberArray))


width = 300
height = 250

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=width, height=height)
frame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

e = Label(root, text="Arraylist")
e.grid(row=1, column=1)


arrayListLabel = Label(root, text="Array List")
arrayListEntry = Entry(root)
arrayListButton = Button(root, text="Enter", command=lambda: arrayList(arrayListEntry.get()))
arrayListButton.grid(row=0, column=3)

sortButton = Button(root, text="Sort", command=lambda: selectionSort(numberArray))
sortButton.grid(row=2, column=1)

randomButton = Button(root, text="Randomise", command=lambda: randomiser())
randomButton.grid(row=3, column=1)

arrayListLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
arrayListEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This is my swap method in another class, ignore the last line as that is only for the console for me to see what is happening

```
# Swap function for swaping the index in the array
def startSwap(array, firstIndex, secondIndex):
    swapObject = array[firstIndex]
    array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex]
    array[secondIndex] = swapObject
    print("Number " + str(array[firstIndex]) + " swapped with number " + str(array[secondIndex]) + " in array\n")
```

[image: Main gui screenshot]

Comment: which function is your `root.after()` method supposed to call? If you just wanna change the color at each step, use `e.config(bg='<enter new color here>')` to change the background color of the label OR use `e.config(fg='<enter new color here>')` to change the color of the font. Add this config statement after each call to `Swap`

Comment: I used what you said right after `Swap.startSwap(numberList, i, minimumIndex)` line of code but it only changed the whole label fonts colour and not each individual number

Comment: You cannot change colors for individual characters in a Label. Try using a `Canvas` with `create_text` or generate `n Labels for n numbers`

Comment: Because there is a limit that you added(only 10 numbers), you could add 10 labels and everytime you click a certain button it changes both the colors and texts( example: ```Label1.config(text=variable, bg=colorvariable)```)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `frame` widget as it was complicating the task of changing the color of the entire background.

**I made the following changes inside the**  `startSwap()` **function to change the colors at every step of the algorithm**

First I created a list of color names:

`colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow']`

Next, I randomly set the `foreground` color from the `colors` list. You can add other colors to increase randomness of color selection.

`e.config(fg=random.choice(colors))`

Finally when the the list of numbers are sorted, set the foreground color to `green` inside of the `selectionSort()` function

`e.config(fg='green')`

**Here's the entire working code:**

```py
import random

from tkinter import *

#import Swap

root = Tk()

# define label before using it
e = Label(root, text="Arraylist")
e.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

numberArray = list()

def arrayList(number):
    arrayListEntry.delete(0, END)
    numberArray.append(number)
    e.config(text=str(numberArray))
    #print numberArray

def randomiser():
    for i in range(10):
        numberArray.append(random.randint(1,100))
        e.config(text=str(numberArray))
        #print numberArray

def startSwap(array, firstIndex, secondIndex):
    # color list
    colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange']
    # set a random color from the colors list
    e.config(fg=random.choice(colors))
    swapObject = array[firstIndex]
    array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex]
    array[secondIndex] = swapObject

# Main selection sort function
def selectionSort(numberList):
    for i in range(len(numberList)):
        minimumIndex = i
        for l in range(i + 1, len(numberList)):
            if numberList[minimumIndex] > numberList[l]:
                minimumIndex = l
        #Swap.startSwap(numberList, i, minimumIndex)
        startSwap(numberList, i, minimumIndex)
        e.config(text=str(numberArray))
        root.update()
        root.after(1000)
        e.config(text=str(numberArray))
    # once numbers are sorted, set foreground as green
    e.config(fg='green')

arrayListLabel = Label(root, text="Array List")
arrayListEntry = Entry(root)
arrayListButton = Button(root, text="Enter", command=lambda: arrayList(arrayListEntry.get()))
arrayListButton.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

sortButton = Button(root, text="Sort", command=lambda: selectionSort(numberArray))
sortButton.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10)

randomButton = Button(root, text="Randomise", command=lambda: randomiser())
randomButton.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)

arrayListLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
arrayListEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Lastly, I added some padding to the `Label` and `Button` widgets.

Comment: It changed the whole frames colour, not the numbers on the label. Try running it yourself to see the error

Comment: I have updated the code. Now it changes the color of all the numbers in the label, *not each number inside the label*.

Comment: Still not i want. Each number that is being swapped needs to be coloured, the person above stated that i need to implement a canvas instead